# AuthorizeAttribute em Controlller e Actions

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net

Ao usar um atributo (AuthorizeAttribute) desenvolvido por mim (com uso de Enums) o mesmo não esta funcionando como deveria da seguinte forma:

Quando usado para decorar a declaração do Controller:

```
[UserTypeAuthorize(TipoUsuario.Administrador)]
public class UsuarioController : BaseController
{ ... }
```

Ele funciona normalmente como deveria, porém ao usar nas **Actions** dentro deste mesmo controller, pelo que sei, deveria sobrescrever o do controller somente nesta Action na qual esta decorada com seus outros Enums ou então com o uso do 
**[AllowAnonymous]**.

A idéia é que os atributos nas Actions devem sobrescrever ao definido na declaração do Controller, assim como o [AllowAnonymous] faz perfeitamente.

```
[UserTypeAuthorize(TipoUsuario.Administrador)]
public class UsuarioController : BaseController
{ 
    //não funciona
    [UserTypeAuthorize(TipoUsuario.Administrador, TipoUsuario.Moderador)]
    public ActionResult Edit(Guid id)
    { ... }

    //deveria funcionar somente para Moderador
    [UserTypeAuthorize(TipoUsuario.Moderador)]
    public ActionResult Edit(Guid id)
    { ... }

    //funciona
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Edit(Guid id)
    { ... }
}
```

Meu AuthorizeAttribute:

```
    public class UserTypeAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
    {
        public UserTypeAuthorizeAttribute(params TipoUsuario[] tiposUsuario)
        {
            Roles = string.Join(",", tiposUsuario.Select(u => u.ToString()));
        }

        protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
        {
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult(FormsAuthentication.LoginUrl);
        }
    }
```

OBS: Os usuários autenticados estão com o seus tipos corretos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> A idéia é que os atributos nas Actions devem sobrescrever ao definido na declaração do *Controller*, assim como o `[AllowAnonymous]` faz perfeitamente.

Na verdade não é bem assim. `[Authorize]` é aditivo, então quando você faz:

```
[UserTypeAuthorize(TipoUsuario.Moderador)]
public ActionResult Edit(Guid id)
{ ... }
```

"Moderador" e "Administrador" estão autorizados a receber o resultado da *Action*.

Tem o mesmo efeito desta outra *Action*:

```
[UserTypeAuthorize(TipoUsuario.Administrador, TipoUsuario.Moderador)]
public ActionResult Edit(Guid id)
{ ... }
```

O que você deve fazer para este caso é desistir de usar na decoração de *Controller*. Use apenas a decoração por *Actions*, explicitando quais permissões podem ser usadas.